# Copy entire values of 2 columns from one table to another ensuring the relationship

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a table `STUDENT` with columns `st_id,name,age,dept_name`. Now I want to create a new table `STUDENT_DESC` with columns `st_id,dept_name,st_desc`. So I need to copy all the values of `st_id` and `dept_name` to the newly created table `STUDENT_DESC`. I need to ensure relationship while copying `st_id` and `dept_name` , the `dept_name` should be corresponding to `st_id`.So how can I do it in PL/SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
insert into STUDENT_DESC (select st_id, dept_name, null from student);
```

this will simply copy all the records. The third column `st_desc` is left empty (null)

To ensure referential integrity you would add a primary key and a referential integrity constraint to the `STUDENT_DESC` table

However, note that in many cases it could be "wrong" to introduce a second table containing student data like that.  It could be "better" to add `st_desc` to the `STUDENT` table.

Comment: more specifically I used `insert into STUDENT_DESC (st_id,dept_name) select st_id,dept_name from STUDENT`. And I think its okay!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand your data model, but at face value you can create your table simply:

```
CREATE TABLE student_desc AS SELECT st_id, dept_name FROM student;

ALTER TABLE student_desc ADD (st_desc VARCHAR2(..));
```

Fill in the `..` with the desired max size for `st_desc`.